# Query information_schema.columns to return output column names and value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to write a query to select a column and value with information_schema clause. I tried a few options but still did not work for me.

I try the following:

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE
table_name='tblmst_app' AND table_the_column_is_from.app_id = 'some_id'
```

The return output that i want it should like:

```
Column Name   | the Values
===========================
app_id        | 20
```

Comment: try giving `table_name` in caps like `TBLMST_APP`

Comment: It didn't work. But now i decide to use another query and i've got the result that i want. Thank you..

Comment: Please post it as an answer

Comment: list spelling of tables with 'select table_name from information_schema.columns'